# Filling a Column in a Dataframe conditionally using values from another Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have 2 dataframes one is the lookup dataframe called 'database' and another dataframe called 'df' for which the values are to be filled conditionally with the values from the 'database' dataframe column called 'Value'

- I have tried -- df['Value'] = pd.np.where but it doesn't work
- I have tried -- np.equal.outer but it doesn't work either

I tried merge and it works but it doesn't conditionally fill in values, I want to fill in the values for every row with '1' in the 'Variab' column of df, 'col2' is just an empty column so ignore that.

Thanks in advance!

Before: df

| ID | Variab | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A2 | 1 |  |
| A2 | 1 |  |
| A3 | 0 |  |
| A3 | 1 |  |
| A4 | 1 |  |
| A3 | 0 |  |
| A3 | 1 |  |
| A4 | 1 |  |
| A3 | 0 |  |
| A3 | 1 |  |
| A4 | 1 |  |

Before: database

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A2 | Ball |
| A3 | Sky |
| A4 | Bird |
| A5 | Fly |
| A6 | Pizza |

After: (the objective)

| ID | Variab | Value | col 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A2 | 1 | Ball |  |
| A2 | 1 | Ball |  |
| A3 | 0 |  |  |
| A3 | 1 | Sky |  |
| A4 | 1 | Bird |  |
| A3 | 0 |  |  |
| A3 | 1 | Sky |  |
| A4 | 1 | Bird |  |
| A3 | 0 |  |  |
| A3 | 1 | Sky |  |
| A4 | 1 | Bird |  |

Comment: share the code that you tried so far

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `mask` before `merge`:

```
df['Value'] = df.mask(df['Variab'].eq(0)).merge(db, on='ID', how='left')['Value']
print(df)

# Output
    ID  Variab  col2 Value
0   A2     1.0   NaN  Ball
1   A2     1.0   NaN  Ball
2   A3     0.0   NaN   NaN
3   A3     1.0   NaN   Sky
4   A4     1.0   NaN  Bird
5   A3     0.0   NaN   NaN
6   A3     1.0   NaN   Sky
7   A4     1.0   NaN  Bird
8   A3     0.0   NaN   NaN
9   A3     1.0   NaN   Sky
10  A4     1.0   NaN  Bird
```